# Pages won't load after redirecting website in https

Tags: linux, laravel, ssl, apache2

I have a wildcard ssl from a third party vendor enabled it in our server. 
I first tried to implement it on our staging site (staging.site.com) and it worked just fine. But when I enabled it in our live site(site.com) it only loads the homepage but if you will click on other pages (site.com/blogs) it says webpage not found "The requested URL /blog was not found on this server".
 We are using ubuntu 14.4, apache2 and laravel as our framework. 
Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have your laravel project folder in your server? with all views and controllers?
Because I m using the same environment, I never faced such problem.

Comment: yep I do and I have the same implementation with my staging site.

Comment: try with `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`